# MySQL Update first instance of a record

Tags: mysql

What im trying ot do is update the first instance of a record based on contact_id.

I have a table of email addresses and corresponding contact_id's. Each contact may have more than one email address so the table can contain more than one instance of the same contact_id.

I want to update the corresponding is_primary field to '1', when I hit the first instance of each distinct contact_id.

I'm not too concerned about what ends up being the primary email address as long as everyone in the database has one.

Table Example:

```
 contact_id   | email        |      is_primary
---------------------------------------------
 1001         | john@world.com      |0
 1001         | desmond@world.com   |0
 1002         | person@life.com     |0
 1003         | preson@help.com     |0
 1003         | bad@sql.com         |0
 1003         | have@searched.com   |0
```

So the result im looking for would be:

```
 contact_id   | email        |      is_primary
---------------------------------------------
 1001         | john@world.com      |1
 1001         | desmond@world.com   |0
 1002         | person@life.com     |1
 1003         | preson@help.com     |1
 1003         | bad@sql.com         |0
 1003         | have@searched.com   |0
```

Have tried creating a temp table and macthcing to that, but query updated all is_primary fields. I know im missing something basic here, but my sql skills are limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This technique joins the table against itself in a subquery, but it only matches one row (based on contact_id *and* email matching. The trick is that the subquery returns just one of the email addresses using MIN, theoretically the first one alphabetically (not reliable, but you said that didn't matter).

I have tested this with good results.

```
UPDATE 
  email 
  JOIN (SELECT contact_id, MIN(email) as email 
        FROM email GROUP BY contact_id) as singles 
  USING(contact_id, email) 
set is_primary=1;
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks good so far. Will do some more tetsing, 5 mins or so. One more question, what if the same email address appears more than once, assigned to different contact_id's. This query should ignore that right?

Comment: Yes, if it's assigned to a different contact_id then it will be fine. That's what `USING(contact_id, email)` ensures (that is selects from the sob query based on matching both columns, not just the email).

Comment: Everything checks out. Thanks mate, really got me out of a hole.