# Update field on first occurence of other_field = value?

Tags: mysql

[Here's the following SQL in SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/537f2/1)

```
+-----+-----+-------------+
| id  | rel | content     |
+-----+-----+-------------+
| 1   | 1   | example 1   |
| 2   | 2   | test 2 oops |
| 3   | 1   | example 2   |
| 4   | 2   | test 2      |
+-----+-----+-------------+
```

How can I apply `SET content = "test 1"` to **only the first record** `WHERE rel = 2 ORDER BY id ASC` without knowing that record's id? Is it possible to do this without any sub queries?

Comment: have you tries update with limit 1?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424861/mysql-update-first-instance-of-a-record

Comment: @DipeshParmar `JOIN` is a sub query, is it not?

Comment: @MisterMelancholy no its performing joining using subquery...

Comment: Sorry, I misread that answer somehow. I meant the table was being joined with the results of a sub query, which still performs a sub query, and is why that answer didn't work for me. @DipeshParmar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming 'first' means the first row when result is ordered by id:

```
update example set content = 'test 1' where rel = 2 order by id limit 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that everyone would assume ordering by id ascending. I added a clarification to my question. Also, I didn't think `UPDATE` and `LIMIT` could be used together. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Error Code: 1221
Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY